# Critic Badge not awarded instantly

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

I recently down-voted this off topic question: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132940/chess-championship
Why was I not awarded the badge "critic" within the next minute? It seemed to work almost instantly on other SE sites.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but maybe it only works for answers? Depends, if you tested it on questions on other SE sites, then it might be a caching issue.

Comment: It also might be the case that the question was deleted before you received the badge, preventing it from being awarded to you.

Comment: Weird, I've also downvoted and VTCd several off topic questions and have only received it once..

Answer (score 3):

> Badges are handed out in batches throughout the day, different batch jobs handle different badge types.

Source: [When are badge calculations done?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189909/164922) on mother meta.

You must have been lucky on other sites.

I note that you [do have the badge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/7/critic?userid=40994), awarded about half an hour after posting this question, so as a support issue I think it is resolved.